# PHP upload files to server script doesnt upload everything

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload

I'm using php and ajax to upload some files to my server, I can upload txt files, images, docs, zips,pdf...
I uploaded **pdf of size 15m**b but when I tried to upload **txt size 14mb** script crashed
Here is my code

```
<form id="form" action="db/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/formdata">
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="file">\
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit" id="">\
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
//Click event for Upload new File button
$('#edit_window .file_container').on('submit', '#form', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();

//Code for uploading file
//get file data
      var file_data = $("#file").prop("files")[0];
      var form_data = new FormData(this);
      form_data.append('file', file_data);
      form_data.append('link', id);

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'db/upload.php',
        data:form_data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        //  $("#feedback").html(data);
        }
      });
    });
```

PHP

```
<?php
    session_start();

    //Prevent running the script if no one is logged in
    if(!isset($_SESSION["CurrentUser"]))
            exit();

    $link = $_POST['link'];
    $target_path = "../data/".$link."/";

    $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES[ 'fileToUpload' ][ 'name' ] );

    if ( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES[ 'fileToUpload' ][ 'tmp_name' ] , $target_path ) ){
       echo "Upload complete!";
    } 
    else {
         echo "Error uploading!";
    }

?>
```

USER.ini

```
upload_max_filesize = 40M
post_max_size = 40M
max_execution_time = 10000
max_input_time = 10000
```

Javascript output

```
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined index: fileToUpload in C:\wamp\www\elmar\db\upload.php on line <i>8</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0020</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>245888</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\elmar\db\upload.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\upload.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
</table></font>
```

Comment: Did you check the `php error log` its an obvious first please to look

Comment: The most obvious thing you are _not doing_ is you dont check the `$_FILES[ 'fileToUpload' ][ 'error' ]` before attempting to do something with a file that may not have actually arrived. [See **Example 1** on the manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Comment: When it happens that the file upload fails, i get Undefined index: fileToUpload  and Undefined index: link
I'm working on getting php error log

Comment: Display the `$_FILES[ 'fileToUpload']['error']` [here are what the error codes mean](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

Comment: I really dont know how to display this error but this is what javascript posts..is this what you were looking for? I eddited my question

Comment: Oh you are using WAMPServer, all the logs are held in the `\wamp\logs` folder look for `php_error.log`

Comment: It logged this
[23-Jul-2015 17:03:51 Europe/Paris] PHP Warning:  POST Content-Length of 3493995 bytes exceeds the limit of 3145728 bytes in Unknown on line 0 Haha I really dont know what this Paris is about

Comment: Paris is because this param in php.ini is set to paris `date.timezone = Europe/Paris`

Comment: Ok that error means you have exceeded the allowed space for POST

Comment: Nevermind that ;) where is this content-lenght limit set, and why havent i changed it with my user.ini file And by the way this file is 1.66MB that i tried to upload, here it says its around 3.5

Comment: Did you change this parameter in php.ini? `;user_ini.filename = ".user.ini"` if not is will not be reading from a user.ini, change the parameters in php.ini itself

Comment: I changed the value from 3M to 40M in php.ini, restarted the server and it works great
Now the problem is why user.ini didnt do the same thing. in php.ini there is a line ;user_ini.filename = ".user.ini" yes, but what does it mean

Comment: Well the most obvious thing is the `;` (semi colon) at the start of the line which means its been commented out and therefore php will not be looking for a `user.ini` file